# C++ get return type for template argument

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, return-type-deduction

I have

```
template<typename DistanceFunc>
class C
{
    using DistanceType = // the return type from DistanceFunc

public:
    C(DistanceType distance, DistanceFunc f)
    : m_distance(distance),
      m_f(f)
    {}

private:
    DistanceType m_distance;
    DistanceFunc m_f;
};
```

How do I derive the return type from `DistanceFunc` for `DistanceType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I derive the return type from DistanceFunc for DistanceType?

Another solution could be use template specialization.

You can declare `C` as receiving a `typename`, without defining it

```
template <typename>
class C;
```

Then you can define a specialization of C receiving a (pointer to) function type as follows

```
template <typename DistanceType, typename ... Args>
class C<DistanceType(*)(Args...)>
 {
   using DistanceFunc = DistanceType(*)(Args...);

public:
    C(DistanceType distance, DistanceFunc f)
    : m_distance(distance), m_f(f)
    {}

private:
    DistanceType m_distance;
    DistanceFunc m_f;
};
```

As you can see the function type is resolved as a return type and the types of the arguments. Now `DistanceType` is simply deduced (as return type) and you have to recreate `DistanceFunc`.

You can use it as follows

```
int foo (int, long)
 { return 0; }

// ...

C<decltype(&foo)> c0{0, &foo};
```

Starting from C++17 you can also add a deduction guide

```
template <typename DistanceType, typename ... Args>
C(DistanceType, DistanceType(*)(Args...)) -> C<DistanceType(*)(Args...)>;
```

so you can declare a `C` object simply as

```
C c0{0, &foo}; // C<decltype(&foo)> is deduced
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I derive the return type from DistanceFunc for DistanceType?

Depends. How is called a function of type `DistanceFunc`?

Suppose is called with an `int`, you can try something as

```
using DistanceType = decltype(std::declval<DistanceFunc>()(std::declval<int>()));
```

If you have the types received from `DistanceFunc`, using `decltype()` and `std::declval()` you can simulate a call to the function and obtain the resulting type.